# Angular2 Firebase, remove Item

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this function to post data to my Firebase:

```
fbPostData(name,type){
  firebase.database().ref('/Workouts').push({
    name:name,type:type
  })
}
```

I just cant sort it out how to remove an item from Firebase.

Comment: please have look at this. https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/2-retrieving-data-as-objects.md#deleting-data

Comment: could you possibly find a better title to your question?

Comment: Based on what conditions do you want to remove the item? Based on its name? Based on its type? Based on its name + type?

Answer (score 1):

**Try some thing like that**

```
import { AngularFire, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      template: `
      <h1>delete</h1>
      <button (click)="delete()">Delete</button>
      `,
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      item: FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;
      constructor(af: AngularFire) {
        this.item = af.database.object('/Workouts');
      }
      delete() { 
        this.item.remove(); // remove data.
      }
    }
```

For more info [Visit](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/2-retrieving-data-as-objects.md#deleting-data) following link.